# for archive_command use an script rather than a command

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.3

I want to create a configuration to get a PostgreSQL HA. In my Master I want to configure a postgresql.conf file with this:

```
archive_command = 'local_backup_script.sh "%p" "%f"'
```

instead of:

```
archive_command = 'cp "%p" /path/to/archive/"%f"'
```

Then I have a doubt: Where do I have to put the script?

Comment: In short, you need to make sure your local_backup_script.sh is available on the $PATH for whichever user you are running Postgres under, or you need to specify the full path to local_backup_script.sh in archive_command.

Comment: I have created a bin_path=/var/lib/postgresql/X/bin directory if I copy my script here, then you say that I have to run `archive_command = '$bin_path/local_backup_script.sh "%p" "%f"'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it wherever you like, so long as the `postgres` user has permission to execute it, and permission to cd into the directory it's in.

I usually put it in `/usr/local/bin` unless I'm working on a system that has a versioned repository of scripts, in which case it's in there - something like `/opt/mycompany-scripts/postgresql/myarchivescript.sh`.

I recommend using a fully qualified path to make its location obvious, e.g.

```
archive_command = '/usr/local/bin/pg_archive_wal.sh "%p" "%f"'
```

(calling it "backup script" is misleading; it isn't doing backups at all, it's just archiving WAL, which may be *part of* a backup or replication process).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* put it anywhere that PostgreSQL can find and execute it.

I put it in the data directory itself, because I consider it to be configuration in the same way the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf and such are, and want them to be backed up together.

(That is also the directory that will be searched for the script if you don't specify a path to it.  At least on Linux)